# Loading additional javascript code from firefox add-on content script

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm writing something that I want to release as both a chrome extension and a firefox add-on.

The chrome extension is [already available on github](https://github.com/fizbin/killfile-extension). I've factored my code into several modules using a module load format similar to what requirejs uses; I did this to separate the parts that were chrome-specific from the parts I hoped to re-use in the firefox add-on.

Specifically, I split up not only the backend work, but also the content scripts.

In chrome, when my content script needs to load another module, it sends a message to the background page saying "please load this module"; the script on the background page then does:

```
  function onLoadLibrary(request, sender, sendResponse) { 
    var allFrames = request.allFrames || false;
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(
      sender.tab.id, {file: request.library.toLowerCase()  + '.js',
                      allFrames: allFrames},
      function () {
        sendResponse({});
      });
    return true;
  }
```

That is, I'm able to load additional javascript into the same sandbox as the content script that asked for that code. This is necessary to make module dependencies work.

In firefox, I can't figure out how to do this. I'll attach my initial content scripts through `pageMod`s and by calling `tab.attach` from the "ready" event of `tabs`. That seems straightforward, but then if that content script needs to load more code I can't see how to do it.

There doesn't seem to be a way to access the sandbox my content script is running in from the `main.js` file so that I might inject more code into it. Even if I somehow kept a reference to the relevant `tab` instance (which only lets me inject into the top frame in any case), it appears that each new call to `tab.attach` puts injected code into a new sandbox. The object `tab` that's passed to my ready event handle isn't a real XUL tab that I could pass to `require("tabs/util").getBrowserForTab`; if it were, then I think I can follow through enough of the sdk code to create my own sandbox, though I'd worry about leaving accidental memory leaks behind.

I considered passing the code back to the content script through a "eval-this-code" message, but I really don't want to use `eval` in my extension because of security concerns; I also worry that using `eval` would make it difficult to impossible to get my firefox add-on approved for [AMO](https://addons.mozilla.org/). (Also, how would that interact when my add-on runs on sites with a Content Security Policy?)

The usage of `traits` to define the add-on API seems to close off access to objects such that I can't reach inside a `Worker` to get a reference to the sandbox my content script is executing in. At this point, it appears that I'd need to include nearly a full copy of the sdk in my add-on just to expose one method on `WorkerSandbox`.

**Note:** I'm using the Add-On sdk (the project formerly known as JetPack). I'm willing to use `Components.utils.import` if someone can tell me how to use that from inside an Add-On SDK-managed content script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content-scripts do not expose a public API to attach more scripts to a content-script sandbox after it was initialized. You should probably file an [enhancement bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Add-on%20SDK&component=General) and state your use case, if there isn't one filed already (search first), and/or even [come up with some patches](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/) yourself.

In cases where there is a DOM that your add-on own (`widget`), then it's just a matter of attaching another script tag.

For things like `page-mods` where there is no DOM you own, you're left with a couple of *options*, none of which is really satisfying. As you already found out yourself, the use of traits prohibits you from accessing "private" properties/methods.

- Fork `page-mod`/`tab`/`content-worker` to provide the functionality you need. That would require creating your own copies of the modules and expose the necessary APIs to inject scripts into existing workers.

  This is has a steep learning curve (but given that you already figured out details such as traits, should be doable for you), but more importantly hard to maintain as you need to make sure you keep up with the upstream. And AMO editors will not like you very much for it :p

  On the plus side, you could try to get your stuff committed upstream, fixing this problem for everybody and become a hero to many authors using the Add-on SDK.
- The `eval` method you propose. Not only is this `eval` a major source for security issues, but it also may be a performance killer, as right now IIRC `eval`ed code will not use the JIT. And, of course, it will make us AMO editors cringe, even if used "correctly".
- Do not use lazy loading at all, and specify all content scripts from the very beginning. This is what add-ons usually do (I'm almost inclined to say "always"). However, this conflicts with your current design, and depending on your add-on may pose a serious performance penalty for loading stuff you didn't really need in the end.
- You could use the `require` mechanism to have most scripts as SDK module and not content-scripts. This is not always feasible, of course, e.g. when dealing with code that would normally modify the DOM in your content-script, but might work for some other stuff.
- Replace `page-mod`, etc with your own Greasemonkey-like, enhanced API. This means lots of work, it is error-prone, security-sensitive and has to be maintained. So, it's not really a viable solution, IMO...

`Components.utils.import` does not help you. It isn't available to content-scripts anyway.

Comment: And I'm going to see if I can refactor some stuff so that I don't do lazy loading on the FF side - I'll still use my module system, but in the background script I'll compute the full dependency tree before making my `page-mod` or `tab.attach` so that when I load modules in the client script sandbox I can specify everything up front in an order that won't need to go back for missed dependencies. That'll be a bit more divergence between chrome and ff than I'd like, but it should still keep the stuff that's likely to change in the future as code that's shared between the two.

Comment: Computing the dependency tree in a sandbox on the background page and then loading the client scripts with everything needed does indeed appear to be a viable approach. Accepting answer...